# Running `apt-get upgrade` with Chef Solo

Tags: ubuntu, chef, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm using Chef Solo to provision a Vagrant VM based on Opscode's "Bento" box for Ubuntu 12.04. When it's done provisioning and I SSH in for the first time, the MOTD tells me there are packages and security updates. I then run `sudo apt-get upgrade` manually, which removes the message on subsequent logins. Is there a way to automate this step with Chef? The "apt" cookbook doesn't seem to handle this. All my Google searches find things only about `apt-get update` but not `apt-get upgrade`. I could just execute the apt-get command in my Chef recipe, but during the upgrade process, there is a pseudo-GUI on a pink screen where I have to select drives for installation (I think this is called GRUB, I'm new to Ubuntu) and I'm not sure how this part can be automated with Chef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just encountered this exact issue myself with chef+vagrant and found the following worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow grub-pc
```

This allows you to reconfigure grub-pc and select the device (if any) you want grub installed on. Setting a device as default here should allow an upgrade that includes grub to not prompt for a device selection. At this point you could create a new vagrant box and use that as your default.

**or**

To run an apt-get upgrade/dist-upgrade without being prompted you could use:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

- `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` uses the default answer to any prompt.
- `Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef"` ensures dpkg only overwrites config files you haven't modified
- `Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"` ensures the current config file is not overwritten. New config files are created with .dpkg-dist suffix.

Comment: That command took me through a similar series of pink GRUB screens, including the same device selection I encounter when running `apt-get upgrade`. :|

Comment: Well as I explained in my answer that is what it should do. It allows you to run an apt-get upgrade from that point on without a prompt. You could bundle it up and create a new vagrant base box at this point. Modifying my answer to give you a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "-y" will get past the prompts.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

You should do this before the chef run, because chef may have cached the package versions in the apt database.

Comment: Vagrant runs Chef Solo automatically when building the VM, so I'm not sure how I would run the upgrade "before" the Chef run. I tried just running the command with -y inside my main recipe, and it seemed to be processing fine, but then (presumably when it got to the GRUB part), it spat out a bunch of random characters to my shell and killed the whole Vagrant process.

Comment: Using the `-y` parameter does not help with the GRUB interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to jtimberman himself, you should not run apt-get upgrade automatically.

The opscode recommended way to upgrade is on a package by package basis using the package resource.

```
package "php5-curl" do
  action :upgrade
end
```

For more details, read [Don't run apt-get upgrade automatically in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080876/apt-get-update-and-apt-get-upgrade-in-chef#15093460)